# Create a list of result from Parse.com NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsstring

I have to create a list of result from a Parse.com database.
The field is a NSString, and i'm using Objective-C.

In fact i have this field like a sequence of numbers

Database is like this : 
row 1 : 4-7-9-6-18 
row 2 : 5-3-8-9-29
row 3 : 32-8-67-3-5
...

Each line, can't have the same number in the sequence.

the goal is to create a list according to the reference sequence.

Let's say that the reference sequence is 3-8-9-44-60

I want to create a list from the Parse.com data like this

Lign 2 has 3 matching numbers
Lign 3 has 2 matching numbers
Lign 1 has 1 matching numbers

Is anyone has i clue, i would be nice to share :)

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Comment: have you tried anything so far? is there any reason you dont store the numbers as an actual array via parse?

Comment: i have no idea how to make this happen, i can use if course a PFquery like  <br>PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"numbers"];
 [query selectKeys:@[@"number1"]];
 NSArray *results = [query findObjects:nil];
 NSLog(@"%@",[results description]); but once i got the results the listing showing the 3 matching also appear on the 2 listing and on the one listing

Comment: Could you paste the output of your `NSLog(@"%@",[results description]);` line?

Comment: you got for the request of 3 matching numbers (Line 2 has 3 matching numbers) for the request of 2 matching numbers (Line 2 has 2 matching numbers, Line 3 has 2 matching numbers) and for the request of 1 matching numbers (Line 2 has 1 matching numbers, Line 3 has 1 matching numbers, Line 1 has 1 matching numbers). The problem is that i do not want that a line which got 3 matching numbers also appears on the other requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to store the sequences as strings, my suggestion is that you do it in following steps. I will not write the code for you - but give you a guideline:

1. Find the rows in Parse.
2. Take the results, convert each of them from the `NSString` to a `NSArray` and put them into another `NSArray` called `sequenceList`.
3. Take the reference sequence `NSString` and convert it into another `NSArray` called `referenceSequence`.
4. Create a new `NSMutableArray` called `sequenceScore`.
5. Create a function that runs through each of all the results in the `sequenceList`.

   5a. Compare each of these arrays with the `referenceSequence`. Get the number of matching numbers (the score) in the two arrays.

   5b. Place the actual result from `sequenceList` on the `sequenceScore` scoreboard by placing the first result (results[0]) at index 0 in `sequenceScore`. The next results you should compare the score of the actual result and the previous results, there is already placed on the `sequenceScore`
6. You should end up with an array (`sequenceScore`) where the different sequences from Parse is placed in order, so index 0 at `sequenceScore` is the sequence with that matches the most with the reference sequence (`referenceSequence`).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, so for the later green mark ;), was out of town for a while. Thanks Simon

Comment: NP @Olico. Glad I could help :)